# Why does Jupyter in VS Code say "No module named 'gensim'" when it's already installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the below setup, I've made sure that the Python version running in Jupyter and the terminal is the same. Yet Jupyter still give error `No module named 'gensim'` when it is already installed. Why is that?

[image: screenshot of VSCode showing the problem]

Comment: I bet Jupyter isn't using your conda environment. Also FWIW, `pip` might not be using the same version of `python`, so to be sure, you can use `python -m pip`. Or you could use `conda` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Try to `Restart Runtime` from Menu Bar on top before doing `from gensim import corpora`

Comment: Based on suggestions of wjandrea and [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gensim), I suggest running in a cell in your notebook `%conda install -c anaconda gensim`. Then when it finishes succesfully, restart the kernel and try the import statement. Fall back to `%pip install` if conda doesn't work. The magic install commands used in cells inside the notebook insure the installations occur in the environment your notebook kernel is actually using, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

I insist that this may be related to the choice of the Python kernel.

You can try running code `! pip install gensim` in the code cell to install the package to solve and verify it.

[image]

If it can be installed and run correctly, you are likely to have chosen an incorrect Python kernel with the same version.